# Using OpenCV without an IDE

Tags: c++, opencv, beagleboard

I need to run a C++ program using OpenCV on a BeagleBoard running Angstrom. I know how to do this with an IDE (The program itself is ready), but I don't know how to compile it without one. I realize that I need to make a Makefile, but I'm not too familiar with Make.

Can anybody give me some pointers?

Comment: Just putting this out there. I do know how to use make at a basic level; I'm just not very comfortable with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/linux_gcc_cmake/linux_gcc_cmake.html#linux-gcc-usage) is a tutorial about using OpenCV with CMake. It will generate makefile for You. On the other hand, just as Billy L said, You should look for a make tutorial, because without this kind of knowledge You will be somewhat disabled as a programmer...

Answer (score 0):

In its simplest form, a makefile is pretty much just a list of commands, separated by labels. By convention, the label `all` is usually used as a sort of default.

The makefile consists of:

```
label1: [dep1 ... depN]
<tab> command1
<tab> command2

label2: [dep1 ... depN]
<tab> command1
<tab> command2

...
```

A traditional beginner's mistake is to indent using spaces, but make wants commands to be indented using a single tab character.

For a simple case, you can ignore the dependencies.

So, the simplest makefile will be something along the lines of:

```
all:
<tab> cc -o hello -Wall hello.c
```

Invoking `make` in a directory where a file like the above exists as `Makefile` will cause `cc -o hello -Wall hello.c` to be invoked. If your make is really picky, you may need to explicitly say `make all`, but that should not be necessary.

There's about a million possibilities with makefiles, but the above should get you started. Strictly speaking the above examples are for GNU make, but makefiles are so ubiquous I don't see other implementations doing the basic use case very differently.